# Measuring the Performance with the Hermes Engine

Tags: javascript, react-native, javascript-engine, react-native-hermes

I am trying to profiling in React Native and using hermes engine. I want measure the time in  between a function call.
In Js We can use console.time or performace.now  but when I am using those fucntion with hermes engine I am getting **"Undefined is not a function"** Error.

When I am running the same code with Chrome debugger it is working fine.

Can anyone suggest how i can implement the below code with the hermes engine.

```
const checkTime = () => {
   console.time('time_NoOp');
   doNothing();
   console.timeEnd('time_NoOp');
   
};
```

.

[image]

Comment: You can use [Date.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) before and after, and subtract the two. Make sure to measure Hermes in release mode with compiled bytecode, as running from source in dev mode is significantly slower, especially on load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

I am able to solve the problem by using the below code

```
const PerformanceTime=() => {
   const t0 = performance.now();
   doNothing();
   const t1 = performance.now();
   console.log(t1 - t0);
}
```